# Form send verification

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I want make protection on form, if user after using form want send another message in less than a minute he should get refuse. Other way every thing should pass.

For now I got something like this on view:

```
      <!-- If Success form message send display this -->
      <?php if (isset($_GET['msgSuccessSent']) == 1) { ?>
        <h1 class="page-title text-center">Dziękujemy za wysłanie wiadomości</h1>
        <div class="text-center">
          <a href="form.php" class="btn btn-default text-center">Wyślij kolejną wiadomość</a>
        </div>
      <?php } else { ?>

        <?php if (isset($_GET['msgTimerError']) == 1) { ?>
            <div id="errorMessage" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Przed wysłaniem kolejnej wiadomości musisz odczekać conajmniej minutę.</div>
        <?php } ?>


        <!-- If message isn't sent display form -->
        <h1 class="page-title text-center">Formularz kontaktowy</h1>

        <!-- Contact form -->
        <form action="contact_send.php" method="post">

          <!-- First name input -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">Imię</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Wpisz swoje imię">
          </div>

          <!-- Second name input -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="secondName">Nazwisko</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="secondName" name="secondName" placeholder="Wpisz swoje nazwisko">
          </div>

          <!-- Phone number input -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phoneNumber">Telefon kontaktowy</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Wpisz swój numer telefonu">
          </div>

          <!-- Email address input -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Adres e-mail</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Wpisz swój adres e-mail">
          </div>

          <!-- Message textarea -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Treść wiadomości</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>

          <!-- Send message button -->
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Wyczyść formularz</button>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Wyślij</button>


        </form>
        <!-- Contact form end -->

      <!-- End of If message isn't sent display form -->
      <?php } ?>
```

And this is my contact_send.php file:

```
<?php
  // Uncomment if you want to use session to check last form send
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['time'] = date('H:i:s');

  header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

  # Database connection settings
  $dbHost = 'localhost'; // database hostname
  $dbName = 'contactForm'; // database name
  $dbUser = 'root'; // database user name
  $dbPswd = ''; // database password

  // Set connection
  $connectionDb = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPswd, $dbName);
  // Check connection
  if ($connectionDb->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $connectionDb->connect_error);
  }

  mysqli_set_charset( $connectionDb, 'utf8'); // change charset for mysqli to utf8

  # Require ContactSend and DatabaseQuery class
  require 'contact.class.php';
  # Get ContactSend class
  $sendEmail = new ContactSend();

  $ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // get user ip address
  $currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // get Date time when user send form
  # ***
  # Here I check if time of last form send is greater than minute
  # ***
  $sqlCheck = "SELECT * FROM contactForm WHERE ipAddress = '$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]' AND dateSend > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)";
  if ($connectionDb->query($sqlCheck) === TRUE) {
    $sendEmail->redirectToForm('form.php?msgTimerError=1');
  } else {

  // insert form values into database
  $sqlQueryInsert =
    "INSERT INTO contactForm (
      firstName,
      secondName,
      phoneNumber,
      email,
      message,
      dateSend,
      ipAddress)
    VALUES (
      '$_POST[firstName]',
      '$_POST[secondName]',
      '$_POST[phoneNumber]',
      '$_POST[email]',
      '$_POST[message]',
      '$currentDate',
      '$ipAddress'
    )";

  // if data was save send mail and redirect to form
  if ($connectionDb->query($sqlQueryInsert) === TRUE) {

    # Get Parametrs from form
    $sendEmail->sendTo = "kuchar.rafal@gmail.com"; // here insert your email address that you want get mails
    $sendEmail->subject = "Tytuł wiadomości"; // here insert Subject of email
    $sendEmail->firstName = $_POST['firstName']; // get user first name
    $sendEmail->secondName = $_POST['secondName']; // get user second name
    $sendEmail->phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber']; // get user phone number
    $sendEmail->email = $_POST['email']; // get user email address
    // make mail content and insert form values into it
    $sendEmail->message = "
      Imię: " . $_POST['firstName'] . "
      Nazwisko: " . $_POST['secondName'] . "
      Numer telefonu: " . $_POST['phoneNumber'] . "
      Adres email: " . $_POST['email'] . "
      Wiadomość: " . $_POST['message'];

    $sendEmail->mailSender(); // send mail

  } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sqlQueryInsert . "<br>" . $connectionDb->error; // display error if database connection or query has error
  }

  // close connection to database
  $connectionDb->close();
  // redirect to form
  $sendEmail->redirectToForm('form.php?msgSuccessSent=1');

}
?>
```

`$msgTimerError` should display if in database exist row with user IP and date of create is less than minute other ways it should just display form.

`$sqlCheck` is for check in database if time of last form send is greater than minute if its not it redirect user to `form.php` with `msgTimerError=1` with method get, otherwise it will add new form values to database and send mail.

Comment: Thank you for sharing a status report with us.  Was there a *question*?

Comment: `if ($connectionDb->query($sqlCheck) === TRUE)` is the wrong approach. You need to check if that row exists. That only tells you if the query didn't fail.

Comment: is there easy way to just check is sql query did get something from database ?

Comment: you're also leaving your database open to a serious sql injection. I hope this isn't a live site (yet).

Comment: Nah I just want make it work with this and then I want to make js validation.

Comment: *"then I want to make js validation"* - that won't help you protect your database and what if they disable JS?. That's up to you if you want someone to clear it all out and start over again and having to re-enter everything "after the fact". Again; check if the row exists. that's what needs to be done here.

Comment: you mean to secure it with `$mysqli->real_escape_string` right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i changed line in contact_send.php so it works... (im so ashamed...)

```
    # Check if user send form less than minute, if true return to form with error
  $sqlCheck = "SELECT * FROM contactForm WHERE ipAddress = '$ipAddress' AND dateSend > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) LIMIT 1";
  $result = $connectionDb->query($sqlCheck);
  if (mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $sendEmail->redirectToForm('form.php?msgTimerError=1'); // return to form page
  } else {
```